# Weak pointer to unique_ptr using get()

Tags: c++

Simple question, just want clarification that using `get()` on `unique_ptr` is like getting a weak pointer, since it has no responsibility and could be left dangling when `unique_ptr` is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. If you have a regular pointer, which is what `get()` returns, it's your responsibility to ensure you only dereference it during the object's lifetime.

It's not really like a weak pointer though. A dangling weak pointer *knows* that it is dangling. A regular pointer has no idea.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: The OP mentions a "weak pointer". In this context that could be taken to refer to C++11's `std::weak_ptr`. You certainly do not get a `std::weak_ptr` by calling `get` on a `std::unique_ptr`, only an ordinary pointer, as you state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as get() will just send you a reference on this pointer and will not grant you the ownership on this pointer.
So if the pointer is deleted the "getted" resource will not be accessible, and your "getted" pointer won't have to be deleted.